# Error Launching Kotlin spring boot application in Eclipse

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse, kotlin

I have been trying to launch a spring boot app written in kotlin on Eclipse IDE(latest) but to no avail.

Java fails to find the main class.

Below is my configuration file:
[image]

This is the error i'm getting:
[image]

I have tried a number of solutions:

1. Add 'Kt' on the build path. Failed
2. Rollback the kotlin eclipse plugin to older versions. - Jetbrains deleted old versions
3. Tried to manually update the build path: - Java cant find the main class
   [image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't trust Jetbrains, use [_Enhanced Kotlin for Eclipse_](https://github.com/bvfalcon/kotlin-eclipse-2023) instead.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Be smarter by avoiding the vendor lock-in trap. Please respect that this question is about Eclipse and that software recommendations and advertising commercial products are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Software recommendations are generally off-topic on Stack Overflow. So please stop bothering others with that. Your personal favorite tool might be fine for your needs, but it doesn't even work for mine. This question is about a different tool. Yes, maybe you are right and Jetbrains lied, but there is a pretty well maintained fork for more than three years now.

Comment: Guys I gave up on this. Will just continue to use good old Java. Thanks for your comments.